# Integrate $\int\frac{e^{\arcsin x} + x + 1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

does anybody have an advice how I can integrate this $$\int\frac{e^{\arcsin x} + x + 1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ I tried substitution $\arcsin x=t$, but was not able to finish it.

Comment: What are you missing, this change of variable makes it trivial ?

Comment: The substitution should help...

Comment: "I tried substitution arcsinx=t, but was not able to finish it" We really must know where you were stopped, to answer meaningfully your question.

Comment: Yeah, I already got it. Sorry, for trivial question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it really does)

Comment: @Kugelblitz it did)

Comment: @Did passed it already, anyway thx

Comment: Alright. No problem :)

Comment: Remember, a problem is trivial to some, difficult to others, so don't out yourself down. It's an interesting question for math amateurs like me nonetheless!

Comment: @Kugelblitz thank you for the support. I agree with you ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this. When you substitute $arcsinx=t$ you got really good output. $$\int\frac{e^{arcsinx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ if $arcsinx=t$ => $dt=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and the integral transforms into $$\int e^tdt=e^{arcsinx} + C_1$$ The whole answer is $$e^{arcsinx} -\sqrt{1-x^2} + arcsinx +C$$ Thats it.